# Maven2 how to run some goal before plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have maven-plagin and need to run goal, that should automatically run before plugin. It possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "run before plugin"? Do you want to run a goal from your plugin before the build?

Comment: May be my question in bad. I'd wont to run goal just before plugins working.

Comment: I recently asked a similar question and got a response that showed me how to create an extra lifecycle to invoke the additional plugins. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427740/how-do-i-execute-a-set-of-goals-before-my-maven-plugin-runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can script it out and string it together like this:

```
mvn clean assembly:assembly
```

for example...

Answer (score 4):

If you always want to execute a goal at a specific point during the build you can add the following to your `pom.xml`. The really interesting part is the `<phase>...</phase>` tag, where you can specify the exact point when the goal shall be executed.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>bar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>foobargoal</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For more information see the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).