# Configure Maven plugins to stick together

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have parent pom which configures certain plugins

```
<pluginManagement>
   </plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
         ...
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         ...
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
         ...
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

And I have tree of poms which are represent integration tests

```
A-\
   a1
   a2
B-\
   b1
   b2
C-\
   D-\
      d1
      d2
```

In each a,b,d products I do

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem is when I will need to add fourth plugin to integration test process for example my custom plugin I will need to move
through all of the integration modules and do manual adding.

**You can advice me to remove `<pluginManagement>` to allow all child just to use them implicitly.**
Yes, but in products which are just 'pom' I don't want plugins to do anything: create some resources and put jboss configuration directories.

I wonder is there some kind of

```
<pluginsBundle>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-integration-test-bundle</artifactId>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</pluginsBundle>
```

To allow me use it just like

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>my.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-integration-test-bundle</artifactId>
      <runOnce>true</runOnce>
   </plugin>
```

**I would like to add option like**

```
<runOnce>true</runOnce>
```

to be able to start application server and deploy target only one time per maven launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a mechanism that does exactly what you need. Your best bet is to define a parent pom with those plugins defined in the build section, rather than the pluginManagement section. In this case the plugin configuration will always be defined. Adding the configuration to a profile in the parent means you can exercise some control over the activation of those plugins.

One refinement to consider is that you can control activation of a profile by the presence or absence of a file. This way you can define the profile in the parent, but have it deactivated in that project because of the marker file being present in the parent. Child projects would not have the marker file in their source, so the profile would be activated for those projects. You can reverse the behaviour by using `missing` instead of `exists` if that makes sense for the majority of projects.

```
<profile>
  <id>build</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <missing>src/main/resources/build.marker</missing>
      <!-- or if you want to enable the profile when the file does exist:
      <exists>src/main/resources/build.marker</exists-->
    </file>
  </activation>
  <build>
    </plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

---

Alternatively, you could try writing custom plugin with a lifecycle that executes all the required mojos in a forked lifecycle. I recently answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427740/how-do-i-execute-a-set-of-goals-before-my-maven-plugin-runs) with details of how to do this.

Another alternative is to write another plugin that uses Maven shared-io to apply a descriptor
to the pom, that descriptor can define arbitrary configuration that is merged into the pom. Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231561/how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects/1265428#1265428) describes how this can be done.

Comment: I can't use parent pom with <plugins> section in the build because I don't want pom with modules to trigger plugins.

Comment: What about the other options I outlined?

Comment: I've looked at your 'shared-io' answer and honestly it is not clear to me how can I use it.

Comment: Ok that's fair enough, I'll elaborate some time later today.

Comment: Ha! I tried same thing with defined properties for activation in the poms. But profile was turned on/off before property was calculated.

Comment: Any links to implement 'once' behavior?

Comment: if you only want to implement it once, you can configure the marker files only in the project you want it activated. This is a bit clunky though.

Comment: No. I mean you can start from any module or sub-module and be sure that all the plugins will only be triggered once and from the point of start.

Comment: oh I see, you can't really without writing your own plugin. Check out this blog for details: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/05/how-to-make-a-plugin-run-once-during-a-build/

Comment: The BIG problem is that <missing> element checks against current directory, and you cannot use ${project.basedir} here.

So, it does not work if you install from directory other than this module itself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to declare a bundle of plugins that could be used somewhere else... but there is inheritance.

What about creating a pom with the `<plugins>` declaration in the `<build>` section and inheriting from this pom in your integration tests projects? This looks like feasible.

Comment: I wrote about this case. I don't want simple poms with <modules> to trigger plugins