# Can maven projects have multiple parents?

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven-2, code-organization

We have Java and Flex projects. We currently have 1 base pom that contains the configurations we want to use for both projects. Problem with this is: Flex projects inherit configuration, for example, for `javadoc` and `pmd` plugins, which is not desirable.

I want to clean it up and have a real base pom, and then a `java-base-pom` and a `flex-base-pom`. But how does this work in a multi-module that has both a Flex part and a Java part?

We have plugins to our own application where we use the following structure:

- my-plugin

  - my-plugin-client (flex)
  - my-plugin-server (java)

`my-plugin` just contains a `pom.xml` with `<modules/>` section. I would use `my-plugin` pom.xml as a parent for both, but then I cannot also use the java base-pom or the flex base-pom as parent. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: I think I am asking know a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449258/maven-unreachable-parent-pom-in-unusual-relations-setup

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A project can have only one parent (unlike multiple inheritance in C++) but this parent can be part of a bigger parent hierarchy. As pointed out by others, you could thus have something like this:

```
base-pom/
|-- flex-base-pom
|   |-- my-plugin-client
|   |   `-- pom.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- java-base-pom
|   |-- my-plugin-server
|   |   `-- pom.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
 `-- pom.xml
```

That said, I noticed you wrote that your actual problem is that:

> flex projects inherit configuration for javadoc and pmd for example, which they do not want.

You should use the [`pluginManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) element to avoid this situation:

> ***pluginManagement*** is an element that is seen along side plugins. Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children. The children have every right to override pluginManagement definitions.

So, in the parent pom, configure your plugins in `pluginManagement` (javadoc and pmd  for example), and reference them within the `plugins` element in the desired children (only in my-plugin-server here). This would solve your current issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but like I said in a comment to the other answer, this is not a structure I can use. If nothing else pops up, then pluginManagement might be the only way to do it. Drawback is then that I cannot enforce PMD on all java projects, since it is only in the pluginManagement and the project itself has to add it to his own plugin section.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. With the current state of Maven, using pluginManagement will be the best solution.

Answer (score 51):

Even though maven projects have single parent, they can import any number of other pom's like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-shared-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This has two important differences compared to a parent:

1. Plugins defined in the imported pom won't be imported
2. Dependencies defined in the imported pom won't be added to the current pom, **it will only import dependencies into the dependency management section**

However, if your parent pom has a `<dependencies>` section and you want to include those into *your* dependencies, then you can add the parent to your `<dependencies>` section just like a regular dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-shared-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Even though the same dependency is already imported, the version tag has to be specified again. To reduce duplication, it can be stored in a property

Comment: adding <type>pom<type> should resolve problems in eclipse if only dependency inclusive parent pom pose any

Comment: Is it at all possible to include plugins from the imported pom?

Answer (score 6):

The only way is to have base-pom as parent of java-base-pom and flex-base-pom.

I have similar structure for my spring projects:

```
base-pom (basic configuration - eclipse, reports, repositories, etc)
|
+ spring-base-pom (spring definitions)
  |
  + spring-jar-base-pom (jar specific definitions)
  |
  + spring-war-base-pom (spring web and servlet dependencies)
    |
    + spring-webapp-base_pom (spring web mvc dependencies)
```

Comment: Agreed. How would multiple parents work anyway - what would happen if both parents had conflicting properties?

Comment: The child overrides the parent, so settings in java-base-pom will override those of base-pom, child1 those of java-base-pom, etc. This way java-base-pom and flex-base-pom are unrelated.

Comment: I am having difficulties doing multiple levels of hierarchy - on my third level (analogous to your spring-webapp-base_pom) the pluginManagement part from parent gets omitted altogether. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

I've cross this exact proble also, and the best solution I found was to use Inheritance and Aggregation as suggest in this question :  [does maven support multiple parents (multiple inheritance) ?](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/does-maven-support-multiple-parents-multiple-inheritance-tp91159p91162.html)

> You can have an aggregator pom that is not the parent of the projects it 
>   aggregates.

and explain in the [Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)

> Inheritance and aggregation create a nice dynamic to control builds through a single, high-level POM (...) Conversely, a POM project may aggregate projects that do not inherit from it.

From this I had my POMs inheritance (pom-master contains communes configurations, and each children the specifics ones) :

```
pom-master
  |-- pom-java
  |-- pom-flex
```

and so my project can get the specifics for each modules configurations as wished :

```
project (aggregate project-flex & project-java)
  |-- project-java
  |      `-- pom.xml => parent = pom-java
  |-- project-flex
  |       `-- pom.xml ==> parent = pom-flex
  `-- pom.xml => parent = pom-master
```

Hope it will help others as well :)

Comment: Hi, how would you set up the maven-site-plugin and maven-release-plugin with this structure?

Answer (score 3):

Just image that `pom.xml` are in fact Java classes: you can have only one parent (or extends a class), but this parent can also have another parent, and so on.

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501294/maven-skip-parent-project-build/1502379#1502379), you must distinguish the parent and aggregation principles in Maven, which means that my-plugin would be considered as an aggregation project, not necessarily a parent project for both my-plugin-client and my-plugin-parent.

So to summarize:

`my-plugin` will define the base pom for all your projects. Then, you create two new **pom** projects: `java-base-pom` and `flex-base-pom`. They have both `my-plugin` as parent. Now, my-plugin-client will have `java-base-pom` as parent, while my-plugin-server will use `flex-base-pom` for his parent.

This way, my-plugin-client will inherit all properties defined in the `my-plugin` pom.xml, and also from `java-base-pom` project.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear enough. The base poms should be at the root of the hierarchy because the application itself also depends on it, or any other java module we build. It is just that next to that I also have this plugin structure which would need kind of 2 parents, but this is not possible it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple inheritance with profiles:

You create (multiple) profiles in the root pom, and auto activate any variation of these profiles achieves multiple inheritance of maven configuration.

Comment: This is not ideal because child projects cannot control the activation of profiles defined in the parent POM.

Comment: This is not remotely related to inheritance. But you can use them to setup some parameters to turn on/off with a switch (enabling/disabling the profiles).