# Maven Project Aggregation and Variables

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Agregate Project 1:

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../module-1</module>
        <module>../module-2</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.parent.pom>../builder-v1/pom.xml</project.parent.pom>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lib.version>2.5.1</lib.version>
    </properties>
```

Agregate Project 2:

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../module-1</module>
        <module>../module-4</module>
        <module>../module-6</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.parent.pom>../builder-v2/pom.xml</project.parent.pom>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lib.version>2.6.0</lib.version>
    </properties>
```

Module 1:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../builder-v1/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <!--<relativePath>${project.parent.pom}</relativePath> not work-->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
```

Section relativePath with variable from aggregate pom not work

```
<relativePath>../builder-v1/pom.xml</relativePath>
<!--<relativePath>${project.parent.pom}</relativePath> not work-->
```

But I need diffrent ${lib.version} in aggregate projects. If I delete inheritance part from
Module 1:

```
    <!--<parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../builder-v1/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>-->

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
```

Variables are not passed to the child modules and i got error:

```
'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.somelib:some-lib:jar must be a valid version but is '${lib.version}'.
```

How can I configure aggregate project and transfer variables into modules?

**UPDATE with @Gab comments**

Parent pom:

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
      <id>v1</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>project.type</name>
                    <value>v1</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>             
          <lib.version>2.5.1</lib.version>
        </properties>
        </profile>
        ...
    </profiles>
```

Module 1:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
```

Agregate Project 1:

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>builder-v1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../module-1</module>
        <module>../module-2</module>
    </modules>
```

When execute builder-v1 goals activate profile **project.type=v1**:

```
mvn clean package --file=pom_v1.xml -Dproject.type=v1 -Dproject.main.module=module-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe define a common parent with 2 profile defining different values for ${lib.version} and automatically activate one profile in your "aggregates" poms. All your module will inherit from the parent one

```
parent-pom (defining 2 different profiles)
|
+ aggregate 1 (inherit from parent-pom - activate profile 1)
| |
| + module 1 (inherit from parent-pom)
  |
| + module 2 (inherit from parent-pom)
+ aggregate 2 (inherit from parent-pom - activate profile 2)
  |
  + module 1 (inherit from parent-pom)
  |
  + module 3 (inherit from parent-pom)
```

**[edit]**
Seems the only trick to automatically activate one profile in your "aggregates" poms to avoid to specify a property in the maven command is

```
<activation>
  <file>
    <exists>relative_path_of_file_specific_to_project</exists>
  </file>
</activation>
```

because the property based activation works only with system properties (not the one defined in pom) and you can't override inherited profile configuration (active by default).

Comment: It's helpful, thanks
I found an worked configuration:
In common parent pom create 2 profiles and set properties. Activate profile by property. Set property when execute mvn: mvn clean package -DsomeProperty=v1

Comment: > no need to specify a property in the maven command

We can't use settings in project pom: Unrecognised tag: 'settings', we can activate profile only in maven settings. It's not what I try to do. I try conf two autobuilding aggregate projects, and this work with activate by maven command

Comment: Missed the setting ;)

Comment: How activeByDefault help me to choose profile? In off docs nothing about that tricks ...

Comment: you're right i thought it was possible to override activation of inherited profile but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want your module to have multiple parents.  This is not possible.  See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636801/can-maven-projects-have-multiple-parents).

You could try suggestion of @Gab. Essentially define two [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) - one for builder-v1 and another for builder-v2.  You can do pretty much anything inside a profile, including specifying different set of modules and different properties/versions.

Comment: Would you recommend to create hier with a common parent for all modules, but 2 aggregation projects?