# Maven unreachable parent pom in unusual relations setup

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I have a maven project where I need to share 2 levels of common project traits.

One level is project-wide things like remote Maven repo (Artifactory), plugin versions, deps versions.

The other is a complicated mapping of actions to Maven lifecycle, shared for "modules" of a special runtime platform.

The parents are nested:

```
com.mycompany:projectfoo-parent
  ^-- parent of:
      com.mycompany:projectfoo-module-parent
```

Each sub-project looks like this:

```
subprojectA/pom.xml  [ROOT]          <--parent-- projectfoo-parent
subprojectA/modules/ModuleX/pom.xml [MODULE] <--parent-- projectfoo-module-parent
subprojectA/modules/ModuleY/pom.xml [MODULE] <--parent-- projectfoo-module-parent
```

All parents are in remote Maven repo (SNAPSHOTS).

Now the issue comes when building in a green field (e.g. CI or with `-Dmaven.repo.local=localRepo`):

```
    [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycompany:projectfoo-moduleX:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:projectfoo--module-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 9, column 13
    [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycompany:projectfoo-moduleY:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:projectfoo--module-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 9, column 13
```

The `-X` shows that Maven doesn't even ask the remote repo for these POMs.

I have tried to place the company's remote Maven repo to the parent, to the module-parent, to `settings.xml`, to the module's pom.xml, ... nothing helped.

**What should I do to make Maven look for these parent POMs in the remote repo?**

**Is my setup even valid? Or is that required that a parent of a (Maven) submodule must be the one that contains it in `<modules>`?** As far as I know, submodules can have arbitrary parent.

A workaround for me could be to bring the parent POMs along and `install` them to local repo before running Maven, because once it's there, the build works just fine.
That also implies that **the ids and versions are fine**. Also, I have checked that the repo IDs and credentials are correct in `settings.xml`. Snapshots are enabled for the repo. Maven documentation for that is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException).

Comment: Are the parent POMs part of the same multi-module project? Or is the `subProjectA` a multi-module project of its on?

Comment: `subprojectA` is a standalone project with it's own Git repo. The parents are in other project and *not* available as source in the same repo.

Comment: It looks like it's a Maven bug. I found a project that has such configuration and used to work few years back. Also, if it is a user error, then Maven fails with error that does not tell the real nature of the issue (unresolvable artifact). I will fill a Maven bug.

But for now, in short: **Submodules can't have different parents than the root module.** I have switched to the normal layout (the root inherits from external parent, submodules have the root as parent).