# Where is Maven's processor-plugin config

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven. Got an issue which is probably resolved by the first answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437718/configure-maven-plugins-to-stick-together?rq=1)

My question is where do I find this plugin configuration? There is no "plugins" section in my pom.xml, so I am guessing it should be somewhere else. I have grep'd for "maven-compiler-plugin" in my project's dir and I cant find it in any file. So where would this plugin configuration be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some "internal" maven plugins (like `maven-compiler-plugin`) have a default, implicit [configuration according to the packaging of your project](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

You can see what is the default configuration with `mvn help:effective-pom`.

In order to override this configuration, just add the `build`, `plugins` section to your `pom.xml`. Once you've added the configuration, just check again with `mvn help:effective-pom`.