# Writing a Maven Plugin/Mojo: how do you make a goal force the execution of other goals?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

*Note: this thread is about writing a custom Mojo, not using a plugin.*

I maintain a [testing plugin](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin) for Maven. Unfortunately, for almost a year now, I've let this particular unknown linger and I'd really like to know how to deal with it so that its users can have a simpler configuration.

Let's say we have two goals in our plugin:

- `prepare` (phase: generate-sources)
- `do` (phase: compile)

I want to configure the `do` Mojo to require `prepare` to have been executed in the earlier phase of the build. However, nothing in the [descriptor documentation](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) suggests I can.

The user probably doesn't care or understand the point of the `prepare` goal, so I don't want to force them to specify it in their POM. Of course, I could execute the Mojo directly from `do`, but then the `prepare` goal will have run at a later phase than is intended.

(I looked into [custom lifecycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427740/how-do-i-execute-a-set-of-goals-before-my-maven-plugin-runs), but that makes it appear that everyone who already has the `prepare` goal in their POMs will have it executed twice upon running `do`.)

Answer (score 3):

You could have something like the below (taken from the CompilerMojo):

```
/**
 * @author <a href="mailto:jason@maven.org">Jason van Zyl </a>
 * @version $Id: CompilerMojo.java 941498 2010-05-05 21:24:11Z krosenvold $
 * @since 2.0
 * @goal compile
 * @phase compile
 * @threadSafe
 * @requiresDependencyResolution compile
 */
```

By setting this over your class, it will execute during the compile phase (in this example). The compile phase requires all the previous phases to have executed first (`validate, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources`...).

Basically, pick a phase after the one you need (or even the same one) and it should work.

Comment: That's how to specify that the `do` Mojo would bind to the compile phase by default and be named `compile` as a goal, but unfortunately I don't see how it says "oh and make sure that 'prepare' was run first".  At this point it looks like the only answer is a custom lifecycle... which I've got working but I'm not sure I like yet.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could try the #maven IRC channel in irc.codehaus.org. Perhaps some of the guys there will have a better suggestion.

Comment: Why the downvote? Yes, this is the older non-annotation based way to do it, but it is still valid.